# Module not found while compiling in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, compiler-errors

While trying to import the `collection-preview.components.jsx` file in the `shop-page.jsx`, there occurs an error saying:

```
"Module not found: Can't resolve '../../components/collection-preview/collection-preview'"
```

URL of the code and the error is shared in the link:  [image: 1]

I would like to know what am I missing here and why the files are not getting compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file called `collection-preview.component` but you import `collection-preview`, just change the name to `collection-preview.component`, it should work

You could also drop `js` and `jsx` ending for files when importing :)

Comment: @ShirishPokhrel if this answered your question, please mark it as the right answer :)